# How do I make all links in WordPress relative?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, reverse-proxy, relative-url

I am doing a reverse proxy to a WordPress website and I need to hide the domain it is on in the source code for web crawlers. The assets in `/wp-content/` will stay on the WordPress site domain, but I need all the posts, pages, archives, author, etc... links to have the domain removed and just be `/path-to-post/`. How do I do this? Example:

From: `href="https://www.wordpress.com/blog/post/name-of-post/"`

To: `href="/blog/post/name-of-post/"`

Comment: Are you using Nginx as the reverse proxy? If so, you could enable the sub module and do it there: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

Comment: @ChrisHaas The reverse proxy is done in CloudFront in AWS, trying the WordPress filters

Comment: @ChrisHaas The WordPress filter solution kind of works, it does replace the string, but it does not keep the post path or ID

Comment: @ChrisHaas Got the filter working correctly. Thanks so much! Woo!